# Swift Combine prevent initial value from triggering sink and prevent duplicates at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a model that has a `myState` Bool and in a controller I sink to it like this:

```
model.$myState
.dropFirst()
.removeDuplicates()
.receive(on: RunLoop.main)
.sink { [weak self] myState in
    print("myState: \(myState)")
 }.store(in: &subs)
```

`myState` is initialized at init as `false`:

```
@Published private(set) var myState:Bool = false
```

I am trying to understand how to avoid the initial sink trigger to happen. I only want the sink to call when `myState` changes value. So if in the model I set it to false when already false, I do NOT want the sink to call. I can achieve that by with the `.removeDuplicates()`, but I still get the initial sink call. So then I added the `.dropFirst()`. With that in I do not get the initial sink call, but, the first time I set `myState` to `false` (when already false) sink is called even though `myState` was already false.

So, in short:

- I only want sink to trigger when `myState` changes from `false -> true` or from `true to false`
- do not want sink to trigger when I setup the sink (dropFirst() works but then I get the initial duplicate edge case).

How can I setup the sink up so that it only triggers if `myState` actually changes (toggles) and also not get the initial sink at setup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you expect the first value to make it sink to be `true`. I that is the case you simply have to swap `dropFirst()` and `removeDuplicates()` around:

```
 model.$myState
    .removeDuplicates()
    .dropFirst()
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .sink { [weak self] myState in
        print("myState: \(myState)")
    }
    .store(in: &subs)
```

Comment: makes sense now. Yes, this is exactly what I was doing wrong. removeDuplicates needs to go before dropFirst. Thanks.